# Standard(s) to store and share geolocation and 3D orientation data for an object, e.g. a raster

Tags: geolocation, photogrammetry, standards

As an example, [GeoTIFF](https://www.ogc.org/standards/geotiff) is a great standard to embed geolocation data into a raster file for cartographic purposes.

But in that case, raster files are usually supposed to be on the projection plane.

What if I want now to share the position (i.e. geolocation) + 3D orientation of an oblique raster (perspective projection) e.g. a simple photograph for example, for which the position and the orientation data are known? For example its position (X,Y,Z) is given as WGS84 coordinates + ellipsoidal height, and its orientation is given as 3 locally defined [attitude angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_(geometry)), such as yaw(Z), pitch(X) and roll(Y).

Does there exist any well established and used (geo-)standardized way to store and share these data, either both together position + orientation (best case) or separately?

Comment: `exif` data of photographs may store such information. Is this sufficient?

Comment: It could, but I can't figure out a tag to properly store the 3D orientation in space. For example, the GPSImgDirection tag "indicates the direction of the image when it was captured. The range of values is from 0.00 to 359.99". It's relative to a North. But what about pitch an roll angles if the object or the raster is rotated about the X and Y axes?

Comment: Okay, it wasn't clear to me you are also interested in pitch and roll. Can't help with that, sorry.